# Clojure - Difference Between Map and Reduce // Converting One to the Other

Tags: concurrency, clojure

```
(defn DoubleFrequency [] 
(def s (slurp "Example.txt"))
(def m (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (inc (%1 %2 0)))
    {}
    (re-seq #".." s)))
(def c (count m))   
(doseq [[k x] m]
    (println k ":" (/ x c))))
```

I'm trying to apply concurrency to my program, and I want to use pmap, but I'm not sure how to work it into my current code here. The functionality is correct for single core, but Ideally I want to replace reduce with pmap in some way and achieve the same results.

Comment: You may want to include the contents of `Example.txt` in your question.

Comment: `map` applies a function to each element of some sequence. `reduce` on the other hand applies a reducing function (gets the init/previous result and the next item out of the sequence) on all or some elements of some sequence. You can implement (some sort of) `map` via `reduce` - but not the other way around. I think for your problem you rather should have a peek at [reducers](https://clojure.org/reference/reducers)

Answer (score 7):

first of all, the function you're trying to make up, is called `frequencies`:

```
user> (frequencies [1 2 1 3 1 4 4])
;;=> {1 3, 2 1, 3 1, 4 2}
```

it is, indeed, single threaded. So let's try to make it parallel.

the initial approach with `reduce` is the right direction, though it's not parallel either, it could be employed to make the parallel one with clojure's standard library concurrency facilities, namely [reducers](https://clojure.org/reference/reducers).

first of all, let's rewrite your reducer function a bit, to do the same thing, but in a more idiomatic way (it is optional, but good for readability):

`#(assoc %1 %2 (inc (%1 %2 0)))` => `#(update %1 %2 (fnil inc 0))`

then we can approach to the parallel reduce with `fold`:

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])

(defn pfreq [data]
  (r/fold
   (partial merge-with +)
   (fn [acc k] (update acc k (fnil inc 0)))
   data))
```

the idea is that it splits your collection by chunks (if it is long enough), and then combines chunks' results with `merge-with`:

```
user> (pfreq [1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 2])
;;=> {1 4, 2 2, 3 1, 4 1, 5 1}
```

notice also, that the collection should be 'foldable'. By default, persistent vectors and maps are foldable, `re-seq` result is not, so you should first convert it into vector: `(vec (re-seq #"..x" s))`, otherwise you won't get any parallelization, falling back to plain `reduce`.

You can obviously approach to this one with pmap, with the same strategy: split -> map -> combine:

```
(defn pfreq2 [chunk-size data]
  (->> data
       (partition-all chunk-size)
       (pmap frequencies)
       (apply merge-with +)))
```

but this is not as flexible and powerful, as the `reducers` pipelines.

Comment: `fnil` is cute.